# Memory corruption when freeing allocated string

Tags: c, malloc, free, corruption

when i try to run this program, i get the error malloc(): memory corruption.
The error doesn't come directly from this function, it happens when i try to malloc() after this function. If i remove the line free(ch) it works correctly so i guess the corruption happens when i try to free it.
The main() is an example of how i would use the function.

```
char * makeInt(int val){ 
  char *res = malloc(5);
  char l [5] = "";
  sprintf(l,"%d",val);
  if(val < 10){
    strcat(res,"000");
    strcat(res,l);
  }
  else if(val < 100){
    strcat(res,"00");
    strcat(res,l);
  }
  else if(val < 1000){
    strcat(res,"0");
    strcat(res,l);
  }
  else if( val < 10000){
    strcat(res,l);
  }
  res[4] = '\0';
  return res;
}


  char * makeString(char *ch){
  int t = strlen(ch);
  char *chaine = malloc(t+4);
  char *nb = makeInt(t);
  strcat(chaine,nb);
  strcat(chaine,ch);
  chaine[t+4] = '\0';
  free(ch);
  return chaine;
}

int main(){
    char *path = malloc(100);
// here we do many operations on path, when i call makeString, path contains something
        path = makeString(path);
    }
```

EDIT: Sorry it was late when i posted and i forgot some informations.
I added makeInt().About include, i have them in my code but i don't think a missed include would cause a memory corruption since it compiles. Also when i call makeString(), path contains a string. I use makeString() at differents location in the code. When i added free(ch) error appeared, but i don't understand why freeing the memory allocated in the main would cause a memory corruption.

Comment: `strcat(chaine,nb);` as `chaine` contents are not yet defined.  Same for `path`.

Comment: in makeString() you try and determine the length of "ch"... which wasn't initialized prior to makeString() being called... as @chux identified above, malloc() does not initialize the memory it allocates for you... either you must do it, or call calloc() instead.

Comment: the posted code is missing the `#include` statements, so does not compile.  (and many of us do not want guess as to what your actual code includes.

Comment: You should pay attention to return types from functions and what type your assigning to what type.  For instance, the function `strlen()` returns a `size_t` and the posted code is assigning it to a `int` type.  If you turn on the warnings when compiling then your compiler will tell you about these kinds of problems that you should fix in the code

Comment: The posted code is calling `makeint()` but that function is not part of the posted code.

Comment: Change `char *res = malloc(5);` to `char *res = calloc(5);` - So that the string is empty and hence `strcat` will work as intended

Comment: C -array indexing is `0`-based, so this `chaine[t+4] = '\0';` writes one-past the array.

Comment: @EdHeal,  the `calloc()` function has two parameters, not just one.  Here is the prototype type:  `void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
`

Answer (score 0):

the posted code contains certain logic errors, for instance:

```
strcat(chaine,nb);
```

but the initial string MUST have a NUL byte, otherwise it is unknown what value would be returned (I.E. undefined behavior)

The returned value from `malloc()` may or may not have a NUL byte in the first character.

This is probably why the posted code is causing a seg fault event.

(you could fix this specific problem by using  `calloc()` rather than `malloc()`

ALSO, the parameter to `makeString()` is not initialized to any specific NUL terminated character string. SO it is undefined behavior to pass that parameter to `strlen()`

(because the first NUL byte encountered could well be beyond the end of the 'path array)

some suggestions:

1. read the man page for any system functions that the code uses.
2. step through any code (preferably with a debugger) to see what it actually does.

here is a version of the code that might work for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf(), sprintf()
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc()
#include <string.h> // strlen(), strcat()

// prototypes
char * makeString(char *ch);


char * makeString(char *ch)
{
    // EDIT: this line was wrong: char *chaine = malloc(sizeof(ch) + 7)  // large enough to handle any int value
    char *chaine = malloc(strlen(ch) + 7);

    sprintf( chaine, "%4lu", strlen( ch ) );
    strcat( chaine, " " );
    strcat( chaine, ch );

    return chaine;  // the caller must call `free()`
} // end function: makeString


int main( void )
{
    char *path = "my path string";
    path = makeString(path);
    printf( "%s\n", path );
    free(path);
} // end function: main
```

and the output is:

```
  14 my path string
```

Comment: `char *chaine = malloc(sizeof(ch) + 7);` Wrong.

Comment: please reconsider how much you malloc. The size of a pointer has nothing to do with this. Also you should use `snprintf` to avoid buffer overflows (int values can exceed 7 ! )

Comment: I corrected the problem with the call to `malloc()`

Comment: @M.M, Since all the strings are of a known length, the usage of 'sprintf()` is a safe operation.  If they were of unknown lengths, then I would have used the `snprintf()`, with a different format string.

Comment: @user3629249 It makes for fragile code - if someone changes `main` to read string from a file for example, and then someone else supplies a file containing a string that is 100,000 characters long, then `makeString` suddenly has a buffer overflow.  IMO it is a good idea to default to making function's correctness be self-contained

Comment: @M.M,  I answered the OPs question, I did not try to produce bomb proof code.